# How do I create an empty matrix in R and update it using a for loop?

Tags: r, matrix

I think this is supposed to be easy but I have been stuck at this for sometime. I need to update a matrix with every loop as follows:

```
          r <- 4
          nlag <- 2

          for (i in 1:nlag){
            a  <- ((i-1)*r)+1
            b  <- i*r
            g  <- beta_OLS[c(a:b),1:r]
            bb <- as.vector(t(g))
          }
```

How do I update the matrix bb with g after every loop?

The beta_OLS matrix looks like this:

```
    [1,]  0.603443440  0.30405670 -0.002150462  0.0090527541
    [2,] -0.003498807  0.16163517  0.056313146  0.0007139815
    [3,]  0.319393118  0.13560199  1.079001883  0.0842017718
    [4,] -0.043669654 -0.92507425 -0.173706846  0.9019772828
    [5,]  0.259785125  0.04053008  0.036206682 -0.0217682012
    [6,]  0.029130279  0.13336440  0.034382991  0.0032809117
    [7,] -0.277746555 -0.25636900 -0.173245066 -0.0636151668
    [8,]  0.046002342  0.48681546  0.131194993 -0.0563989161
```

And I want the output to be look like this in bb:

Every 4 X 1 section stacked one on top of the other.

```
     0.6034
    -0.0035
     0.3195
     0.0437
     0.3041
     0.1616
     0.1356
     0.9251
    -0.0022
     0.0563
     1.0790
     0.1737
    -0.0091
    -0.0007
    -0.0842
     0.9020
     0.2598
     0.0291
    -0.2778
    -0.0460
     0.0405
     0.1334
    -0.2564
    -0.4868
     0.0362
     0.0344
    -0.1733
    -0.1312
     0.0218
    -0.0033
     0.0636
    -0.0564
```

What does it take to create an empty matrix in R, MATLAB code for which is as simple as this?

```
    bb = [];
```

Comment: We are missing alot of information here, like `beta_OLS` or `nlag`

Comment: Are you sure this is the way you want to do this?  In R, using a for loop is almost always the wrong way.

Comment: The output you show and want does not match input you display. How about `as.vector(beta_OLS)`? or `matrix(as.vector(beta_OLS),ncol=1)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone commented already: Don't use loops in R! Took me a long time to learn myself.

```
whatyouwant <- unlist(split(x=beta_OLS, f=c(rep(1, 4), rep(2, 4))))
```

This will give you a named vector. If you don't like the names you can get rid of them:

```
attributes(whatyouwant) <- NULL
```

And if you really want to declare an empty matrix it's easy as `bb <- matrix()`